# Should I fetch data on the server side or client side to populate a select element in Next.js form?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch-api, prisma, next.js13

I'm currently developing a web system using Next 13 where i need to populate a select element and i'm overthinking about a "problem".

I have to populate my select with some data that comes from my database, but this select is inside my form that are client side (and can't be server component).

And my question is, should i fetch the data on the server side and pass to my component as a prop or just fetch it on client side.

This form is used on two routes, the *"/new"* and *"/edit"*.
The problem to fetch on server side is that i will need to fetch the same data on two differente pages, i don't know if doing that is correctly

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to populating a select element in a web system developed with Next.js, you have a couple of options for fetching the data. Let's discuss the pros and cons of each approach:

1- Fetching data on the server side and passing it as a prop:

Pros:

- The data is fetched and processed on the server side, reducing the amount of
  work on the client side.
- The data can be shared across multiple pages or components, ensuring consistency.
- SEO benefits as the populated select element is included in the initial HTML response.

Cons:

- If the data is the same for both the "/new" and "/edit" routes, fetching it on the server side can result in redundant requests.
- If the data is dynamic and changes frequently, server-side fetching might not be the best option.

2- Fetching data on the client side:

Pros:

- Avoids redundant requests if the data is the same for both the "/new" and "/edit" routes.
- Allows for more dynamic updates and avoids caching stale data.

Cons:

- The data fetching and processing will be done on the client side, which may require additional time and resources.
- SEO might be affected if the populated select element relies on client-side rendering.

Considering your specific case, where the same data needs to be fetched for both the "/new" and "/edit" routes, you could opt for client-side fetching to avoid redundant requests. You can fetch the data once and store it in a shared state management solution like Redux, React Context, or Next.js's built-in state management.

Alternatively, if the data doesn't change frequently and you prefer to leverage server-side rendering benefits, you can still fetch the data on the server side, but make sure to implement proper caching mechanisms to minimize redundant requests.

Comment: I think i will do this on client side! thanks for you help and for clearing things up for me.